# How to add an id to fullcalendar events url in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

How to append an id to a fullcalendar event url in Rails ?

I have a json.jbuilder

```
json.array!(@estudiante.clases) do |clase|
  json.extract! clase, :id
  json.id clase.id
  json.title clase.name
  json.start clase.start
  json.end clase.end
  json.dow [1, 4]
  json.url listar_clases_estudiante_url(clase, format: :html)
end
```

And a fullcalendar Javascript:

```
var initialize_calendar;
initialize_calendar = function() {
  $('.calendar').each(function() {
    var calendar = $(this)
    calendar.fullCalendar({
      defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      events: '/estudiantes/listar_clases.json'
    });
  })
};
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', initialize_calendar);
```

The problem is that the events are retrieved from the url `/estudiantes/listar_clases.json`. But I want the url to be `/estudiantes/listar_clases/{whatever_the_estudiante_id_is}.json`

For example:
`/estudiantes/listar_clases/1.json` or `/estudiantes/listar_clases/7.json`, the changing the number being @estudiante.id.

So how do I pass the estudiante id, whatever it might be, to the json `events` url ?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to set the corresponding routes and controller actions in order to allow these kind of requests with the ID. Also the routes does not look very RESTful. It would be better to have a route GET /estudiantes/1/clases. Attach the routes and the controller that is receiving the request so I can give you more details.

Comment: From routes.rb: `get 'estudiantes/listar_clases/:id', to: 'estudiantes#listar_clases', as: 'listar_clases_estudiante'`. And in estudiantes_controller.rb, the function `listar_clases` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the id to the fullcalendar JS, I have to add this to the listar_clases.html.erb view:

```
<div id="idestudiante" style='display:none;'>
  <%=@estudiante.id%>
</div>
```

And in the fullcalendar JS:

```
var initialize_calendar;
initialize_calendar = function() {
  $('.calendar').each(function() {
    var calendar = $(this)
    calendar.fullCalendar({
      defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      events: '/estudiantes/listar_clases/' + $("#idestudiante").text() + '.json'
    });
  })
};
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', initialize_calendar);
```

So that the id of the current student could append to the end of the fullcalendar events url.